# How to create a Material UI element with different initial properties?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to React and MUI. I would like to pass an icon as a prop to another component, and have that component explicitly set the color of the icon before rendering it, depending on some internal logic e.g. the toggle status of some button. Let's assume my component looks something like this:

```
import { Button, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import SyncIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Sync';

const MyWidget = (props: any) => {
  const toggle = true;
  return (
      // how to set the color of the icon to 'success' if toggle is set
      // or to 'error' otherwise?
      <Stack direction={'row'}>{props.icon}</Stack>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (<Stack>
      <MyWidget icon={<SyncIcon/>}/>
  </Stack>);
}
```

Here it is on [CodeSandbox.io](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-urcvtj?file=App.tsx)

The [customization docs show](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/) suggest changing props globally and `styled` only overrides CSS props - not MUI props and I want to avoid using it in the more general case. I am not sure where to start... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the props to accept an icon and color.

CustomComponent.tsx

```
interface CustomComponentProps {
  icon: React.ReactElement; // You can make it strict by using list of known icons in an enum instead of generic ReactElement
}

export default function CustomComponent(props: CustomComponentProps) {
   return <>{props.icon}</>;
}
```

Component.tsx

```
<CustomComponent icon="{<SyncIcon color={conditionMet ? 'primary' : 'secondary'} />}">
```

Comment: Nope, this implies the condition is external - not internal

Answer (score 0):

Found a reasonable solution:

```
const MyWidget = (props: any) => {
  const toggle = true;
  const icon =
    props.icon &&
    React.cloneElement(props.icon, {
      color: toggle ? 'success' : 'error',
    });
  return (
    <Stack direction={'row'}>{icon}</Stack>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox](https://react-ts-erbo7i.stackblitz.io)